# plsql tyring to create a string algorithm

Tags: oracle, algorithm, plsql

I am trying to make a difficult (for me) string algorithm.

Here is a screenshot from how the algorithm has to be:
[image]

So it all starts with a number (which can be variable in length && is varchar).

The steps are:

1. Devide number into groups of 4 (last group can be less then 4)
2. Reverse the group order
3. Remove spaces

After struggling for a couple of hours I so far only managed to splitt the number into groups.

```
DECLARE
    text    VARCHAR2(50);
    newText VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
    text := '3536 2029 2712 3456 789';
    FOR i IN 0..LENGTH(text) LOOP
        IF MOD(i, 4) = 0 THEN
            newText := newText || ' ' || SUBSTR(text, i, 1);
        ELSE
            newText := newText || SUBSTR(text, i, 1);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    dbms_output.put_line(newText);
END;
/
Output: 3353 6202 9271 2345 6789
```

Wat I tried in the last hours was; I firstly thought the most easy way should be split the long text into a groups and add those into a array, after that simpley reverse the array. Honestly this wasn't working out for me at all (not even close). So therefor I came up with this.

Can you help me? Sorry for being newby, started today on plsqy.
If i can provide some extra information I am happy yo post this as well.

**P.S.**

I don't even need to have a exact code example. Some guiding help will be a great help.

Regards

Comment: Why downvote? If some one has feedback on my post(s) I can improve my posts for the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't bother with procedural code when it's not needed, you can do the same transformation using simple SQL query:

```
SELECT
    LISTAGG(GRP) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RN DESC) RESULT
FROM (
    SELECT
        SUBSTR(VALUE, (LEVEL - 1) * 4 + 1, 4) GRP,
        ROWNUM RN
    FROM
        (SELECT '3536202927123456789' VALUE FROM DUAL)
    CONNECT BY
        SUBSTR(VALUE, (LEVEL - 1) * 4 + 1) IS NOT NULL
    )
```

PL/SQL:

```
DECLARE
    text    VARCHAR2(50);
    newText VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
    text := '3536202927123456789';
    FOR i IN 0..TRUNC(LENGTH(text) / 4) LOOP
        newText := SUBSTR(text, i * 4 + 1, 4) || newText;
    END LOOP;
    dbms_output.put_line(newText);
END;
```

or

```
DECLARE
    text    VARCHAR2(50) := 3536202927123456789;
    newText VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
    SELECT
        LISTAGG(GRP) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RN DESC) INTO newText
    FROM (
        SELECT
            SUBSTR(VALUE, (LEVEL - 1) * 4 + 1, 4) GRP,
            ROWNUM RN
        FROM
            (SELECT text VALUE FROM DUAL)
        CONNECT BY
            SUBSTR(VALUE, (LEVEL - 1) * 4 + 1) IS NOT NULL
        );

    dbms_output.put_line(newText);
END;
```

Comment: Hey Husqvik, Thanks for response. The problem is, I need this working as part of an function which has to generate the whole algorithm.. The code example you gave me is by getting data from tables only(?). I need some function in plsql where I can input a number...

Comment: Updated. You can always simply wrap SQL query into PL/SQL procedure/function.